# KeyCloak Events to Azure Event Grid

Tags: keycloak, azure-eventgrid

Is there any easy/configurable way so Key Cloak events can be published to Azure Event Grid? from looking at the documentation and googling I couldn't spot any such thing.

Only thing I found that comes close to it is creating a new plug-in for it and registering it with Key Cloak, so I guess we should be able to use that to post events to Event Grid API. But due to our lack of java skills we'd like to avoid that if some other way is available?

https://dev.to/adwaitthattey/building-an-event-listener-spi-plugin-for-keycloak-2044

Answer (score 2):

There are only two built-in listeners - Logging Event Listener and Email Event Listener - according to the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#event-listener). Anything else needs to be built by implementing the [Event Listener SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_events) like you've mentioned.

While not built for Event Grid, you could try out [this HTTP listener](https://github.com/jessylenne/keycloak-event-listener-http) to send events to a [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview)/[Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) that can transform the payload for [Custom Topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-topics).

*PS: I haven't really tried out the HTTP Listener myself*